# How to fix error: invalid argument type 'NSString *' to unary expression (xCode4)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am new to coding, I am teaching myself by watching tutorials and looking at posted papers on Google, I am following the iPhone Application paper posted by Seth Whiting and Mark Dixon from Southern Illinois University and I get an error while following their model and do not know how to fix it. Error: invalid argument type 'NSString *' to unary expression

```
-(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView*)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)rowforComponent: (NSInteger)component{
    if (component==clientComponent){
        return [clientName objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    if (component==bxComponent) {
        return [problemBx objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    if (component==antComponent) {
        return [anteCedent objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    if (component==conComponent){
        return [conSequence objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}
```

Comment: exactly which line? And show the datatypes for each of the variables used.

Comment: You're also missing a space between `row` and `forComponent`.

Comment: @Rob: got it right.....

Comment: I put a space in between row and forComponent and it still shows the initial error @Rob

Comment: I am new to coding and don't know what you mean by show the datatypes of the variables used @AnoopVaidya

Comment: How do you declare clientComponent, bxComponent, etc.? When you create an instance variable or property, you have to declare what class it is, like @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *myVariable -- NSString is the data type. What are yours?

Comment: Is it just me or does there not appear to be a parameter for the titleForRow: argument?

Comment: property (nonatomic,retain) UILabel *lblClient;
property (nonatomic,retain) UILabel *lblBX;
property (nonatomic,retain) UILabel *lblAnte;
property (nonatomic,retain) UILabel *lblCon;
property (nonatomic,retain) UITextView *dataView;
property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *butEnterSelection;
property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *btnSend;
@rdelmar

Comment: I am completly lost @RicPerrott so I have no idea what you are talking about, can you please explain how to add the correct parameter?

Comment: That doesn't answer the question about  clientComponent, bxComponent, antComponent, and conComponent. What are those??

Comment: here is some NSarray ' NSArray *clientName;
    NSArray *anteCedent;
    NSArray *problemBx;
    NSArray *conSequence;'

Comment: I found this by following [link](http://seab.envmed.rochester.edu/jaba/articles/2012/jaba-45-03-0643.pdf) page 650 is where the error comes out

Comment: Once again, that doesn't answer the question. What is clientComponent?  How do you create it? What is its data type? you keep answering with things that are not in your question. If the error is in the code you posted, then we need to know what those things you're trying to compare are.

Comment: I am really sorry, I have no idea what I am doing. I think component is referring to the picker view and clientComponent refers to client, bxComponent refers to "behavior" antComponent refers to "antecendent" and conComponent refers to "Consequences" which are all examples in the paper I am reading and posted a link to. I think the data type is NSarray @rdelmar

Comment: Could I sen you a screenshot or something that would be it easier? @rdelmar

Comment: I think I am missing the correct data types that you were talking about @annoop vaidya1 can you help me add them?

Comment: I looked at you link, clientComponent is defined like this: #define clientComponent 0. If you did that correctly, then its data type is an int, and your code that you posted should work. You should add an exception breakpoint to see if it will pinpoint the offending line of code. I don't think the problem is in the code you posted.

Comment: `#define componentCount 4
#define clientComponent 0
#define antComponent 1
#define bxComponent 2
#define conComponent 3
#import "FirstViewController.h"`

Answer (score 1):

Probably your code is not malformed, but located at the wrong place. Obviously clang thinks, that "-(NSString*)" is the beginning of an expression with the unary minus sign operator applied on something casted to NSString*. And of course you cannot apply "-" to a reference.

Do the following checks:

1. Is the method inside a @implementation … @end?
2. Is the method outside any other method? A simple forgotten } will place the method inside another method, what gives the text a complete different meaning for the compiler.

It is a good idea to reindent the whole source file using Xcode's reindention feature.

Here is a sample for your mistake:

```
@implementation Subclass
- (void)method
{
    id pickerView;
-(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView*)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)rowforComponent: (NSInteger)component{
}
@end
```

clang:

```
Invalid argument type 'NSString *' to unary expression
```